# Error when I execute "npm run dev" in terminal

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs3

I'm new in Vue3.
What does mean this error message?

Error message in VS terminal

[image: 1]

When I try to execute the command "npm run dev" on terminal, this error message is show to me

UPDATE
The message error says "failed to load config from C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop#Fac\Vue3\learning-vue3\vite.config.js error when starting dev server".
I did open the file "vite.config.js", and this is your content:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Have. you done `npm install` in your project directory?

Comment: Yes. I follow all the commands.
1. npm init vue@latest
2. join in the file
3. npm install
4. npm run dev

I did exactly how is in a tutorial

Comment: Not related, but I would recommend you use `Vite` if you are starting new project, use `npm create vite@latest my-vue-app --template vue` to do that. Here is a link for install page, it might also just work for you? https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project

Comment: Please post your solution below rather than edit the question